# Sharing data between two angular applications

Tags: angular

I have two angular applications in my project (app1 and app2)
In app1 I have shared service:

```
export class SharedService {
  message!:string
  constructor() { }
  setMessage(data:any){
    this.message=data;
  }
  getMessage(){
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

In view1.component.ts which is located in app1 is this:

```
import { SharedService } from 'projects/app1/src/app/shared/shared.service';
export class View1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(private shared:SharedService) { }
  message="View 1 komponenta";
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shared.setMessage(this.message);
  }
}
```

In my app2 (this is separate application inside main folder) i have in view2.component.ts this

```
import { SharedService } from 'projects/app1/src/app/shared/shared.service';
export class View2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private shared:SharedService) { }
  message!:string
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.message = this.shared.getMessage();
  }

}
```

And in view2.component.html, located in app2 I want to display that data defined in app1 like this:

```
<p>Message ki je definiran v view1 app1: {{message}}</p>
```

This works, if this is in one application and sharing between components works with this exact same code (I tried it). But now, when I have 2 applications created with ng generate application app1 and app2 it doesn't work.

Main project is created by following hi
https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: You can move your common service in a separate NgModule and import that module in app1 and app2 applications

Comment: Can you give me more information please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your common service in a separate `NgModule` and import that module in `app1` and `app2` applications. For example :

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {YourCommonService} from '..common_service_path';

@NgModule({
 providers: [YourCommonService]
})
export class CommonServiceModule {
 // add custom logic if you want to 
}
```

In your App1 and App2 modules, import this `CommonServiceModule` :

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonServiceModule} from '..common_module_path';


@NgModule({
 imports: [CommonServiceModule]
})
export class YourApp1Class {
 // app1 module
}


@NgModule({
 imports: [CommonServiceModule]
})
export class YourApp2Class {
 //app2 module
}
```